# Laravel renders form empty

Tags: laravel

I have modals.blade.php file where I keep all models that project needs. In main layout I include that file @include('parts.modals'). When I inspect element in Firefox, I see that form is empty. When I move the modal into main layout it renders as it must be.

[image]

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-contact" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create a Contact</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="form-contact">
                    <div class="form-group">                        
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">                        
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="form-group">                        
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Contact</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably it is something about closing the inputs tags. You may use the inputs as `<input ... />`

Comment: The `.form-group` divs are below your form, so there is probably something wrong with your html.

Comment: There is no problem with html, as it works when I move into main layout. The problem is in rendering.

Comment: Most probably it is all about how the browser interprets the html. If it does work in the  main view but is not working in a child view then you must verify if: the html is well written or there are no duplicated IDs in the final result and so on..